# What is the best approach to test abstract classes with parameterized constructors using NUnit and C#?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, nunit

I am looking for the best way to test an abstract class with constructor parameters. It is important to me that I can also include members that are marked as `protected`. Here is what I came up with. Let's take the following class as an example:

```cs
public abstract class MyAbstractClass {

  public MyAbstractClass(string someParam) { ... }

  protected int MethodToTest(int param1, int param2) { ... }
}
```

One possibility would be to derive the `TestFixture` directly from the abstract class and thus gain access to the members that are marked as `protected`. But what I rather don't like about it is that I have to pass the constructor parameter in the `TestFixture` attribute. Furthermore, I have introduced a magic string in addition to this (admittedly, I could still put it into a constant).

```cs
[TestFixture("constructor param here")]
public class MyTestFixture : MyAbstractClass {

  public MyTestFixture(string someParam) { ... }

  [Test]
  public void ConstructorTest() {
     Assert.Throws<ArgumentNullException>(() => _ = new MyTestFixture(null!));
  }

  [Test]
  public void MethodTest() {
    Assert.That(this.MethodToTest(1, 2), Is.EqualTo(3));
  }
}
```

Another way might be to simply build a class (in the unit test project) around the abstract class and pass the protected member through. Somehow that doesn't seem very practical to me either. Above all, it bloats the file containing the test terribly as soon as the classes get bigger.

```cs
[TestFixture]
public class MyTestFixture {

  private class MyAbstractClassWrapper : MyAbstractClass {
    public MyAbstractClassWrapper(string someParam) : base(someParam) { }
    
    public new int MethodToTest(int param1, int param2) => base.MethodToTest(param1, param2);
  }

  [Test]
  public void ConstructorTest() {
     Assert.Throws<ArgumentNullException>(() => _ = new MyAbstractClassWrapper(null!));
  }

  [Test]
  public void MethodTest() {
    MyAbstractClassWrapper sut = new("constructor param");
    Assert.That(sut.MethodToTest(1, 2), Is.EqualTo(3));
  }
}
```

What do you guys think? Are there any better solutions or do I have to settle with my approaches above?

Comment: Why does the `TestFixture` *itself* have to implement the class being tested?  Why not just create a concrete class which implements it in the tests?  That second approach seems more reasonable, what's wrong with it?

Comment: The thought behind this was that I do not have to write all the code that just passes method calls through. At first glance, the tests also look much cleaner with it than with the wrappers, but they are harder to understand.

Comment: I was wondering if there might be a foreseen way to test such cases. NUnit provides a lot of attributes with which you can do really great things. Oddly enough, this case seems to me to be quite special. Searching the net, I found few useful answers.